# Chromium/chrome running headless: wait for page load when using --screenshot?

Tags: chromium, google-chrome-headless

Trying to take a screenshot using headless Chrome but it executes --screenshot before the page is loaded. On MacOS running zsh, I'm invoking it like this:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome https://example.com/foo.html --screenshot=/Users/myhome/foo.png
```

Is there a way to wait until the page is loaded before the screenshot is taken?

Comment: Have you gone through this page: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/chrome-and-firefox-can-take-screenshots-of-sites-from-the-command-line/? Though it talks about doing it on Windows but the arguments are same

Comment: I did, Asesh, but thank you. Unfortunately that article is somewhat out of date and doesn't work when the page takes a few seconds to load. I finally learned I need to use Puppeteer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is that those command line options don't work well and have been supplanted by Puppeteer. Here's the script I created (hardcodes values for brevity).

Here's the complete code.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}
async function run () {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://twitter.com/gnuman1979/status/1239523796542992387');
  await sleep(2000)
  await page.screenshot({path: './foo.png'});
  browser.close();
}
run();
```

Save as foo.js, then run using node:

```
$ node foo.js
```