# Headless Chrome does not execute JS

Tags: twitter, google-chrome-headless

I'm running a headless chrome to take screenshots of tweets via the [oEmbed API.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/timelines/guides/oembed-api)

Downloading the tweets and creating the HTML works fine, but the embedded JS does not run, which causes the tweets to be unstyled in the screenshot.

When I fetch the created HTML file and open it in my Firefox, the JS is loaded, executed and styles the tweet perfectly.

Is this a problem with headless chrome, twitter itself or something else?

My CLI command looks like this:

```
google-chrome -headless -screenshot=' + filename_image + ' ' + msg.filename + ' -force-device-scale-factor=2 -virtual-time-budget=20000 -window-size=516,3000 --disable-gpu
```

This is from the node-red script which prepares the CLI command which is then passed to the bash via an "exec"-node.

Edit #1: To make it clear: The screenshot works in general, but the result is unstyled, as no external script is loaded and executed.

I've also tried to disable ufw to check whether it's a problem with the firewall. It's not. The problem persists, even with disabled firewall.

Edit #2: I added the `--disable-gpu` flag to get rid of [this error message,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719890/why-am-i-getting-a-failed-to-send-gpuchannelmsg-createcommandbuffer-error) which was also written to the console. Sadly that didn't change anything about the end-result.

Edit #3: Back on this. Tried running the same exact command through a PHP script. Everything works fine, tweets are styled perfectly. Doesn't make this any less strange.

Comment: does it render properly if run from outside Node-RED?

Comment: I just tried that. It renders the screenshot, but also without loading the external scripts.

Comment: Some searching suggests the screenshot arg may have issues with timing of the page load so maybe Google Puppeteer would work better as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61166503/chromium-chrome-running-headless-wait-for-page-load-when-using-screenshot

Comment: I also have this problem.
On local PC web page headless open OK.
On VMware or docker, headless in chrome - web page open without JavaScript. Same py script in FireFox web page opened OK.
Appear more 1 year ago, still i can't solve it.